# iPhone : How to prevent screen stretching into 4-inch display

Tags: iphone, iphone-5

I just want my app to be seen in 3.5-inch area even though it is on iPhone 4-inch display.
I unchecked 'Autolayout' all of the views in IB files but it still uses fullscreen.
Is there any other options for it?
How can I prevent my app to use 4-inch fullscreen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default iPhone apps run letterboxed on iPhone 5 (4-inch display), unless you add a `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image.

If you added a `Default-568h@2x.png` image (or it has been added by XCode) and you want to go back to the letterboxing mode, you will need to

- remove the `Default-568h@2x.png` file
- run a clean build (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>)
- remove the app from the device/simulator

Now build and run the application and it should run letterboxed again.

Comment: Now we are required to provide Default-568h@2x.png if we want to submit a binary. @GabrielePetronella How can we ensure letterboxing while the Default-568h@2x.png image is present?

Comment: I guess you cannot. Probably Apple (rightfully) wants to enforce the transition to iPhone 5 compatible apps.